# ¿Cómo puedo generar un click a un control que tiene eventos customizados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Estoy realizando tareas de automatización para el siguiente link:
https://online.movistar.com.ar/autogestion/loadSelectLocationAction.do

En líneas generales ocurre que en el menú que se está desplegando se puede acceder mediante DOM, pero cuando intento realizar un click a **Capital Federal, Capital Federal**, dicho click no se está realizando. Busqué diferentes puntos como divs, span, que puedan llegar a recibir un evento click, pero no lo reciben o no estoy logrando localizarlo.

Si escribo **Capital Federal, Capital Federal** completo, retorna un solo menuItem (es dinámico). Probé con onclick, fireEvent, dispatchEvent, generar un click con el mismo DOM y no hubo caso.

Para el caso este, la siguiente línea de código no tendría un ID **locationBox_popup0**, sinó **locationBox_popup4**.

El framework que usan es DOJO y las pruebas las hago con HP Quick Test Professional desarrollando en VBScript.

```
<div class="menuItem" id="locationBox_popup0" role="option">
<div class="rightMenuItem" style="width: 70%;">
<span class="comboBoxLastLabel"></span>
<span class="comboBoxFirstLabel">Capital Federal, Capital Federal</span>
<span class="comboBoxLastLabel"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: En la imagen vemos el menú que me trae los inconvenientes]

EDIT:

Porción de código que uso actualmente:

```
nav.EsperarCarga()
'Pantalla localidad
nav.ObtenerSegunNextCode("input#locationBox>{}")

nav.ObtenerSegunNextCode("input#locationBox").focus

nav.TeclearEnFocoActual(JoinExpr("{0}, {1}", Array(localidad, provincia)))
wait 3

dim menu 
set menu = nav.ObtenerSegunNextCode("div[class=RightMenuItem]>span[class=comboBoxFirstLabel]")
menu.onmousedown

wait 10

Function JoinExpr(expr, arrayArgs)
    Dim result, c
    result =expr
    c = 0

    For each arg in arrayArgs
        result = replace(result,"{" & c & "}", arg)
        c = (c + 1)
    Next
    JoinExpr = result
End Function
```

Comment: Tienes algun control sobre los scripts que se ejecutan en esa página? Puedes postear el código que haz usado para probar los eventos?

Comment: Edite para agregar el código

Comment: Parece que la página funciona, ¿conseguiste solucionar el problema?